# Substitute for vector<vector<int>> in python

Tags: python, c++

What is the substitute of vector<vector>a in python?

Will this work?

```
a=[[]]
```

Comment: Did you try it?  Yes, that's how it's done.  Note that you don't usually create it like that.  You'll create a simple list `a=[]` and then append lists to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify it as a list of list of int by:

```
from typing import List

a = [[]]  # type: List[List[int]]
```

Python itself will not complain if you try to append a string:

```
a[0].append('hello')
```

but running `mypy` over it will complain:

```
c:\tmp> mypy vecint.py
vecint.py:6: error: Argument 1 to "append" of "list" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't equal, because `len(a)` = 1.  In C++, an empty vector has size 0.

There's no simple solution, because in Python an empty list is not a list of lists. It's just a plain list.